# D3 Stacked Chart with JSON data

Tags: d3.js

I want to create a Stacked bar chart like http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208 . But I don't want to use CSV file.

How can I change this sample by using JSON data?
Anyone could help?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm

Comment: Yes, I just did it. It doesn't work..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague but let's say we convert that CSV file to JSON data as:

```
var data = [{
    "State": "VT",
    "Under 5 Years": 32635,
    "5 to 13 Years": 62538,
    "14 to 17 Years": 33757,
    "18 to 24 Years": 61679,
    "25 to 44 Years": 155419,
    "45 to 64 Years": 188593,
    "65 Years and Over": 86649
  }, {
    "State": "VA",
    "Under 5 Years": 522672,
    "5 to 13 Years": 887525,
    "14 to 17 Years": 413004,
    "18 to 24 Years": 768475,
    "25 to 44 Years": 2203286,
    "45 to 64 Years": 2033550,
    "65 Years and Over": 940577
  },
  ...
```

Then you would need to fix the pre-processing (to get the keys and totals) as:

```
  // fix pre-processing
  var keys = [];
  for (key in data[0]){
    if (key != "State")
      keys.push(key);
  }
  data.forEach(function(d){
    d.total = 0;
    keys.forEach(function(k){
      d.total += d[k];
    })
  });
```

Then the rest of the example falls into place:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
  .axis .domain {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 40
    },
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .paddingInner(0.05)
    .align(0.1);

  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

  var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

  var data = [{
    "State": "VT",
    "Under 5 Years": 32635,
    "5 to 13 Years": 62538,
    "14 to 17 Years": 33757,
    "18 to 24 Years": 61679,
    "25 to 44 Years": 155419,
    "45 to 64 Years": 188593,
    "65 Years and Over": 86649
  }, {
    "State": "VA",
    "Under 5 Years": 522672,
    "5 to 13 Years": 887525,
    "14 to 17 Years": 413004,
    "18 to 24 Years": 768475,
    "25 to 44 Years": 2203286,
    "45 to 64 Years": 2033550,
    "65 Years and Over": 940577
  }, {
    "State": "WA",
    "Under 5 Years": 433119,
    "5 to 13 Years": 750274,
    "14 to 17 Years": 357782,
    "18 to 24 Years": 610378,
    "25 to 44 Years": 1850983,
    "45 to 64 Years": 1762811,
    "65 Years and Over": 783877
  }, {
    "State": "WV",
    "Under 5 Years": 105435,
    "5 to 13 Years": 189649,
    "14 to 17 Years": 91074,
    "18 to 24 Years": 157989,
    "25 to 44 Years": 470749,
    "45 to 64 Years": 514505,
    "65 Years and Over": 285067
  }, {
    "State": "WI",
    "Under 5 Years": 362277,
    "5 to 13 Years": 640286,
    "14 to 17 Years": 311849,
    "18 to 24 Years": 553914,
    "25 to 44 Years": 1487457,
    "45 to 64 Years": 1522038,
    "65 Years and Over": 750146
  }, {
    "State": "WY",
    "Under 5 Years": 38253,
    "5 to 13 Years": 60890,
    "14 to 17 Years": 29314,
    "18 to 24 Years": 53980,
    "25 to 44 Years": 137338,
    "45 to 64 Years": 147279,
    "65 Years and Over": 65614
  }];

  // fix pre-processing
  var keys = [];
  for (key in data[0]){
    if (key != "State")
      keys.push(key);
  }
  data.forEach(function(d){
    d.total = 0;
    keys.forEach(function(k){
      d.total += d[k];
    })
  });

  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.total - a.total;
  });
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.State;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.total;
  })]).nice();
  z.domain(keys);

  g.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return z(d.key);
    })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) {
      return d;
    })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.data.State);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth());

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 2)
    .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
    .attr("dy", "0.32em")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .text("Population");

  var legend = g.append("g")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", 10)
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(keys.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
    });

  legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", width - 19)
    .attr("width", 19)
    .attr("height", 19)
    .attr("fill", z);

  legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", width - 24)
    .attr("y", 9.5)
    .attr("dy", "0.32em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d;
    });
</script>
```