# Angular, D3 - Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/3BtK3aYltU3jzV5hC9DW?p=preview

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart in Angular using D3.

The chart data needs to be JSON data.

I found an example of a stacked Bar Chart using JSON

[D3 Stacked Chart with JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941427/d3-stacked-chart-with-json-data)

This is what I have based my plunker on within Angular

I'm getting the error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

at this point

```
this.data.forEach((d:any) =>{
    d.total = 0;
    this.keys.forEach((k:any) =>{
        d.total += d[k];
    })
});
```

I'm guessing this is a typescript issue.

How can I stop this error and display the stacked bar chart in Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize your `keys` array on declaration to avoid the error :

```
public keys : any[] = [];
```